# How to find what headers my C++ application is using?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm using some open source (MIT license) project that's composed of headers only.
I'm using only a small fraction of what this project has to offer, and I'd hate to include all the headers in my project for no reason. I created a sample project and included the open source project in it. Is there any way to get a list of all the headers used by my sample project?

To clarify, in my sample project I have:

```
#include "opensourceMainHeader.h"
```

and `opensourceMainHeader.h` has:

```
#include "opensourceAuxiliaryHeader1.h"
#include "opensourceAuxiliaryHeader2.h"
#include "opensourceAuxiliaryHeader3.h"
```

And so on. Then I'd like to get (I'm guessing from the linker or some other tool chain in VC++) the list of headers that are used.

Is that possible?

Comment: Not a duplicate, as this talks about finding the dependents for the entire project (based on C++) rather than a single C file.  This question is also asked better than the other.  It's also not asking for a tool recommendation as suggested by the other question nominated as a possible duplicate.  This question is specific, answerable, and has appropriate detail.  It should be voted up, not down.

Comment: I don't know whether it's available on Windows, but you might be interested in include-what-you-use, as in [my answer to "Self-sufficient header files in C/C++"](/a/30602408/4850040).

Comment: I guess VC has an option /H since g++ has an option -H. (Undocumented: VC accepts dash options. Even the old -o)

Comment: Checking on that, with VC the /H is something undocumented, and the option for listing include files is "/showIncludes" (yes, verbose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project setting in VS that can do this.  Go to the Property Pages for your project, then `Configuration Properties | C/C++ | All Options`.  Enable the `Show Includes` options.  Build your project, and examine output.  This is the `/showIncludes` option.